# Can we replace Lockscreen in Windows Phone with our Prank App Screen?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows Phone App. In Which i am wondering that when i press unlock button of my Windows Phone then my app screen should be displayed. Can Anyone please suggest?
can i do the same as i want.

Comment: You mean as the lock-screen?

Comment: you can apply for permission and get a libary from microsoft but it cost over $3000 last time i checked

Comment: Thankuu ZoomVirus :) Okkk So We can't set our App screen on lockscreen. Can we do same for the Home screen. Where our tiles get display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you are describing can't be done in Windows Phone.
If it was possible every developer would try to place his/her app as the lock screen.

What you can do is [create a tile and badge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868216.aspx) for your application and then the user can choose to display that.

Comment: Thankuu Corcus :) I understand